# Error 1062 in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

```
INSERT INTO order SELECT * FROM order WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

I am getting Error Code: `1062
Duplicate entry '5890738' for key 'PRIMARY'`

How to resolve this as I want only 6 months data but this table contains 6 years data?

Comment: You want to reinsert into the same table? Makes no sense

Comment: I'm with him ^ , you want to duplicate the data?

Answer (score 0):

What you get as error means that you try to insert id (which a primary and unique key) twice times, to solve that you must use something like that :

```
INSERT INTO order(all your columns except Id_column) SELECT all your columns except Id_column FROM order WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

Note : Id must be auto-increment column

Comment: You are assuming the `ID` column is auto increment ?

Comment: @sagi yes, with id auto increment

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO order(all your columns except Id_column)   
SELECT all your columns except Id_column   
FROM order WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```